# Passing children from XHP to ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, xhp

I have an XHP component:

```
final class :common:message-stripe extends :ui:base {
  use XHPReact;

  protected function compose() {
    $this->constructReactInstance( "MessageStripe", Map {} );
    return <div id={$this->getID()} />;
  }
}
```

that should look like this in my `.php` file:

```
<common:messagestripe>
  This is my message :)
</common:messagestripe>
```

On the ReactJS side, the component looks something like this:

```
var MessageStripe = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="message"> {this.props.children} </div>
    );
  }
});
```

However, I get errors about rendering `null` in my ReactJS component, which means that children are not sent correctly. So, my question: how can I pass the children from XHP to ReactJS?

Answer (score 1):

You're not including your children when rendering your XHP component.

```
final class :common:message-stripe extends :ui:base {
  use XHPReact;

  protected function compose() {
    $this->constructReactInstance( "MessageStripe", Map {} );
    return <div>{$this->getChildren()}</div>;
  }
}
```

Additionally, (assuming you built your :ui:base element with attribute forwarding as outlined here: [Building a Good UI Framework with XHP](http://codebeforethehorse.tumblr.com/post/52824249342/building-a-good-ui-framework-with-xhp)) you don't need to manually set the ID of your root element, XHPJS::element() will do that for you.

Comment: show the code for that link. Don't push people there. Let them decide the merit before putting them at risk.